# Gnome control center 17.10 only working when TB3 station plugged in

Tags: 17.10, gnome-control-center, thunderbolt

I recently faced an issue with gnome-control-center refusing to start on my laptop (hp Spectre x360). Starting from the top right menu, I'm getting a spinning cursor in the top bar for about 10 seconds, then nothing. From command line, I'm getting an instant core dump.

When running via command line, response is an instant "Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)" (which is french for segmentation fault). Running under gdb ("gdb gnome-control-center", then "run") I'm getting: Thread 1 "gnome-control-c" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x00007fffd0705687 in XGetXCBConnection () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1

I have a dual boot setup and use windows sparsely for gaming. I have as well a thunderbolt 3/ usb-c external graphic (hp Omen accelerator w/ radeon Rx480) which I used mostly on windows as well. Linux can see the card (after building intel TB driver and setting the TB enclosure as a trusted device) but I can't get the intel integrated graphic drivers and radeon drivers to work correctly together (at least on the built-in laptop screen).

I have just discovered that when the TB enclosure is plugged in to the laptop, gnome-control-panel works absolutely fine. As soon as I boot *without* the external graphics, the panel core dumps again. So the crash seems somehow related w/ the external graphic card.

Any idea how I could fix this without reinstalling everything? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this command: strace -e open gnome-control-center. Output result here.

Comment: thanks for your help but I have now reinstalled - the issue is gone.